# В чем проблема регулярки? [Python3]

Tags: python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Составил регулярку. Коряво, но как только мог:

```
PROFILE = 'Битва семи замков через (.+)\n'\
          '(||||||)(.+), (.+) .+ замка\n' \
          'Уровень: ([0-9]+)\n' \
          '(?:.*)Атака: ([0-9]+) Защита: ([0-9]+)\n' \
          'Опыт: ([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)\n' \
          'Выносливость: ([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) (.+)\n' \
          '(?:Мана: [0-9]+/[0-9]+\n)?' \
          '(-?[0-9]+) ([0-9]+)\n\n' \
          'Экипировка (.+)\n' \
          'Рюкзак: ([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) /inv' \
          'Состояние:\n' \
          '(.+)\n' \
          '(?:\n\nПомощник:\n(.+?) (?:.+?) (.+)? \(([0-9]+) ур\.\) (.+) /pet)?\n'\
          '(.+)'
```

При попытке re.findall() возвращает пустой список.

```
message.text = Битва семи замков через 1ч 34 минуты!

Пейн McM, Рыцарь Красного замка
Уровень: 51
⚔️Атака: 57 Защита: 7
Опыт: 553454/568364
Выносливость: 8/9 ⏰сейчас
0 2

Экипировка +1⚔️+1
Рюкзак: 0/15 /inv

Состояние:
Отдых

Подробнее: /hero


match = re.findall(PROFILE, message.text)
print(match)
```

Пытался проверить регулярку с помощью сайтов. По отдельности всё работает, а вместе работать отказывается.

Comment: Объясните для начала, откуда вы получаете такие данные? Есть варианты для проверки строк сделать проще. Опишите более детально что ты хотите сделать и для чего.

Comment: Данные получаю из сообщения в телеграмм. Я должен получить всю нужную инфу: имя, класс, замок, уровень, атака, защита, опыт, выносливость, монеты и кристаллы, статы от экипировки и (опционально) данные о питомце)

Comment: и все они всегда в таком формате?

Comment: Опциональный только помощник.

Comment: @Let'ssayPie: отсюда: «@ChatWarsBot»

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в символах перевода строки, исправил регулярку немного, с исходными данными из сообщения работает.

```
import re 

PROFILE = 'Битва семи замков через (.+)\n+'\
          '(||||||)(.+), (.+) .+ замка\n' \
          'Уровень: ([0-9]+)\n' \
          '(?:.*)Атака: ([0-9]+) Защита: ([0-9]+)\n' \
          'Опыт: ([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)\n' \
          'Выносливость: ([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) (.+)\n' \
          '(?:Мана: [0-9]+/[0-9]+\n)?' \
          '(-?[0-9]+) ([0-9]+)\n+' \
          'Экипировка (.+)\n' \
          'Рюкзак: ([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) /inv\n+' \
          'Состояние:\n' \
          '(.+)\n' \
          '(?:\n\nПомощник:\n(.+?) (?:.+?) (.+)? \(([0-9]+) ур\.\) (.+) /pet)?\n'\
          '(.+)';

text = '''Битва семи замков через 1ч 34 минуты!

Пейн McM, Рыцарь Красного замка
Уровень: 51
⚔️Атака: 57 Защита: 7
Опыт: 553454/568364
Выносливость: 8/9 ⏰сейчас
0 2

Экипировка +1⚔️+1
Рюкзак: 0/15 /inv

Состояние:
Отдых

Подробнее: /hero''';

match = re.findall(PROFILE, text);
print(match);
```

**Вывод:**

```
[('1ч 34 минуты!', '', 'Пейн McM', 'Рыцарь', '51', '57', '7', '553454', '568364', '8', '9', '⏰сейчас', '0', '2', '+1⚔️+1', '0', '15', 'Отдых', '', '', '', '', 'Подробнее: /hero')]
[Finished in 0.2s]
```